# open eclipse with encoding of the saved file

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, switch-statement

I worked my way through the "eclipse encoding" problems in Stackoverflow. None matches my problem.

I work with files that are windows encoded `(ISO92xx)` AND `UTF8`. I want eclipse to open my files with the encoding that the file is saved with and not the default encoding that is set.

Until now I tried to swtch the default encoding to the windows ending. this messes up my files that are UTF-8 encoded.

Please dont tell me that i have to switch the encoding everytime, when i open the file. Eclipse is such a mighty tool. there must be some kind of a way.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse stores file properties, including its character encoding, in project settings. You can have different properties for each file.

It seems that you don't have a project. Just create one, and, if you don't want to move your files into the project folder, create links to the files via New»File»Advanced»Link….

Comment: ok, that helped me out. Thx a lot.  

but not the best solution when i want to do a short bug fix.